# Encapsulating \ sign

Tags: php, regex

I need to find **$** sign in a string and replace it with **\$** signs.

But when I run the code below I get **\0text** as an output instead **\$text**

How can I get the result which I need?

```
<?php
$text = '$text';

$result = preg_replace('/(\$)/', '\\\0', $text);

die($result); // output is \0text
```

Comment: Use: `echo preg_replace('/\$/', '\\\\$0', '$text');` or `echo str_replace('$', '\\$', '$text');`

Comment: If you're only replacing a fixed character, do you need a regex? `str_replace` would probably be easier.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. Could explain me how to understand backslashes' logic in '\\\\$0'

Comment: In a string backslash needs to be escaped that is why `str_replace('$', '\\$', '$text');` However in `preg_replace` it needs to be escaped twice because replacement string is also passed to regex engine and that also requires another escaping.

Comment: Escaping something means it should not already be escaped. That's the way it is. You can't just escape something and have it mean something after, or when it's undone. Find `'~(?<!\\\)((?:\\\\\\\)*)(\$)~'` Replace `'$1\\$2'`